# Автоматическая замена фотографий в слайдере

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно сделать слайдер для Wordpress, в котором с периодичностью, скажем, в 1 час заменятся слайды. Фото для слайдов берутся из галереи портфолио.

Для слайдера я взял [Owl Carousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/). 
Как я понимаю, мне нужно написать цикл который будет:

1. получать массив всех фото, загруженных в галерею;
2. перебирать массив и выводить в слайдер, например, по 4 фото из массива.

Для таймера думаю взять jQuery таймер и по флагу передавать переменную php, чтобы  через неё инициализировать цикл с перебором массива фотографий.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, примеры такого рода, а то я с php не очень силен. 
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Если вы хотите получать массив всех фотографий сразу, то почему бы не отдавать весь этот массив в браузер сразу, а там уже с помощью js осуществлять его перебор с той периодичностью, которая вам нужна?